# How to update a table with 2 random values, check in and check out dates/columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

In SQL Server how can I update a `LibraryTtable` with 3 random values, that follow a sequence of books in a lib.

The library system has to calculate fines, based on *3 factors*  **checkout**, allowed **duration** (books 30 days, mags 7 days), and finally **checkin** date.

For e.g.

First a Col1 -> `Check-Out Date` then based on a random `NEWID()) % 30` days col2 ->  `Check-in Date` and Col3 -> Originally allowed `Duration` (can be 7 to 30)

I can do this,

```
UPDATE [dbo].LibraryTtable 
SET Check-Out = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 370), '2015-02-01')
```

but how do I hold that in a temp variable and add a random range within a span of 30 days for the check-in date

I can get the random values independently, but I don't know how to store and use them sequentially together.

Comment: Why not just use multiple `update` statements?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do not know how to self refer to the same table and hold the value... I come from C#, and since I do not see a foreach loop.. I do not know to walk the rows and hold the each rows value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write an `UPDATE` query via the CTE.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @LibraryTable TABLE (CheckOut date, CheckIn date, AllowedDuration int, ActualDuration int);

INSERT INTO @LibraryTable (CheckOut, CheckIn, AllowedDuration, ActualDuration) VALUES
(GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 30, 0),
(GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 30, 0),
(GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 30, 0),
(GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 30, 0),
(GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 30, 0);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        CheckOut
        ,CheckIn
        ,ActualDuration
        ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 370 AS RandomNumber370
        ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 30  AS RandomNumber30
    FROM @LibraryTable
)
UPDATE CTE
SET
    CheckOut = DATEADD(day, RandomNumber370, '2015-02-01')
    ,CheckIn = DATEADD(day, RandomNumber370 + RandomNumber30, '2015-02-01')
    ,ActualDuration = RandomNumber30
;
```

**Result**

```
SELECT *
FROM @LibraryTable;


+------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+
|  CheckOut  |  CheckIn   | AllowedDuration | ActualDuration |
+------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+
| 2015-09-07 | 2015-09-10 |              30 |              3 |
| 2015-11-25 | 2015-12-16 |              30 |             21 |
| 2015-06-16 | 2015-06-24 |              30 |              8 |
| 2015-11-25 | 2015-12-07 |              30 |             12 |
| 2015-03-25 | 2015-03-29 |              30 |              4 |
+------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: many thanks, you understand and explained well... better than some of the other thread crappers :)

Comment: @transformer, you are welcome. I'm glad my answer was useful.